# How to stripcolor in inspircd server

Tags: irc

I am creating a chat web app using inspiRCD, i am getting () symbol from the server and after looking around found out that it's a color code i need to use this code to color the texts that iam getting from server.[color code symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CNgn.png) .i already add  in my inspircd.conf file and restart the server
[i already tried this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMCLF.png)

i need a fix for this

Answer (score 0):

See [the stripcolor module's documentation](https://docs.inspircd.org/3/modules/stripcolor/): it does not apply automatically, but provides the `+S` channel mode, so you need to set that channel mode (`MODE #channel +S`)